# Passing out failure reason for a commonly failing method

Tags: c#, error-handling

When you throw an exception, you can put a handy message in to give more information as to why the operation failed.

Obviously throwing exceptions on methods that commonly will die is not good practice.

[This article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229009%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) suggests both the `TryParse` pattern and the `Tester-Doer` pattern, however neither of these patterns allow you to extract any information as to **why** the method failed.

**Is there an accepted pattern for passing out of a safely-failing method which allows you to glean more data of the reason for failing?**

Clearly you could do something like `public FailureReason TryParseWithMessage(string s, out MyClass myClass)` or `public bool TryParseWithMessage(string s, out MyCLass myClass, out FailureReason failureReason)` but these seem a little dirty for the normal case where the method will succeed...

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the second implementation; maybe just make the `message` part be a separate class, not a string, as it may be helpful to provide back line numbers, element names etc but that may be an overkill. Also you can always use your log file if your users aren't meant to see the message

Comment: @StenPetrov I actually meant to do that - I'll update Q accordingly...

Comment: I almost never use `TryParse` unless I consider an un-parsable string to be expected in regular execution.  Unexpected failures, where you can't predict what kind of errors that you'll get, are what exceptions and try/catch are for.

Comment: @SamIam Exceptions are costly and carry the potential of crashing the app. Whatever can be checked should be checked instead of relying on exceptions IMO

Comment: Give _who_ more information about the reason for failure? The human, or the computer? The human gets information in the `Message` property of the exception. What's the computer going to do with the extra information? Answer those questions before looking for patterns.

Comment: @StenPetrov Sam's point is that that's only true when you can do something different with that knowledge.  If you can go back to a user and say "please give me a new value" then sure, it makes sense.  If you're now in a position where you have an invalid string value, are expected to do something with it's int value, and don't know how to continue, sometimes it's better to just throw an exception because only some caller further up the chain is capable of resolving the problem.  In essence, you should be using `TryParse` if you would otherwise catch the exception right there.

Comment: You don't *have* to throw an Exception object, you can also return it.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to return a `Tuple<StatusMessage, MyClass>`.  Then you'd do

```
var result = ParseWithStatus(data);
if (result.Item1 == StatusMessage.Success) return result.Item2;
else
{
    // handle each StatusMessage case that is a failure.
}
```

Or something along those lines (`switch` instead of `if/else`, for instance).

Comment: I would use a name other than `TryParse` as that name implies by .NET use that you're getting a bool. TryParseWithStatus or something like that would do

Comment: @StenPetrov - Good point.  I renamed it to `ParseWithStatus`, because `Parse` is the one that returns the successful value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a special class to encapsulate the results, either the success case or the failure case. Its interface could look like this:

```
public interface IParseResult {
  // whether the operation succeeded
  bool Success { get; }
  // contains error messages, can also be a single string message
  IEnumerable<string> Messages { get; } 
  // the result of the operation in case of success, null otherwise
  MyClass MyClass { get; }
}
```

And then your method can return it:

```
IParseResult Parse(string s) ...
```

I've used it successfully before [here](https://code.google.com/p/nroles/source/browse/src/NRoles.Engine/Core/operation_result.cs) (I called it generically an *operation result*), with a custom [`Message`](https://code.google.com/p/nroles/source/browse/src/NRoles.Engine/Messages/Message.cs) class.

Comment: +1.  This would be the next step up from mine in complexity. If you'd need anything more than a `Tuple<,>`, or you'd need it frequently and not just for the one function, then you're better off with a message passing class like this interface demonstrates.  One change, though - I'd make it generic: `IParseResult<T>`, with a `T Result` instead of `MyClass`.